# Jmeter HTTP response parsing

Tags: xpath, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am currently trying to setup a load test that consists of 5 http requests.

```
1. POST to http://example.com/Confirm
```

This is the initial request where i send out the data, the response contains two hashes that i need to store for later use.

```
2. GET to http://example.com/Verify/${hash}
3. POST to http://example.com/Final/${hash}
```

In the final part, i have to post hash value from the 1st request to the url together with some other response data. I have tried using XPath extractor, though i get the following error no matter what i try:

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.XPathUtil: Type=Val=false Tol=false org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 58; The string "--" is not permitted within comments. jmeter.extractor.XPathExtractor: SAXException while processing (//Response[1]/WI_HASH) The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
```

Are there any other options for response parsing apart from the XPath/Regexp extractor?

Answer (score 0):

In the `XPath Extractor`, Select the `Use Tidy` checkbox.